# How to Append List to Empty List in Python?

Tags: python, list, empty-list

I try this code below

```
lst = [[]] * n
lst[0].append(1)
```

If i print the cod, the result is

```
[[1], [1], [1], [1], [1], [1]]
```

And then I try manual way to make an empty list like below

```
lst = [[], [], [], [], [], []]
lst[0].append(1)
```

The result showing up

```
[[1], [], [], [], [], []]
```

Is there any differences between `lst = [[]] * n` and `lst = [[], [], [], [], [], []]` ?

Comment: This exact question was just asked a few hours ago. :) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60348228/python-filling-array-in-the-loop#comment106753907_60348228

Comment: Try printing `id` of each inner list when you do `[[]]*n`.

Comment: Sorry, my friend, I'm new here, but I got it. I cant search the keyword for the article, so I made new one. Thanks for the response

Answer (score 0):

when you multiply your list of lists with n you are repeating only the reference  to the same initial list so basically you have only one list and many references to the same list and when you are modifying one element you are modifying all; when you create "by hand" you have different lists